# parachain-system can not get ParachainInherentData After runtime upgrade

Tags: runtime-upgrade, cumulus, block-production, parachain-system

Before this `setCode` upgrade, our parachain works well.
After `setCode` upgrade, we get the following error log.

```
Jun 02 09:39:36 Parami-AWS-SFO-DANA-01 parami[490]: 2022-06-02 09:39:36 ⚠️ ParachainSystem declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(0)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(1)`
Jun 02 09:39:36 Parami-AWS-SFO-DANA-01 parami[490]: 2022-06-02 09:39:36 panicked at 'validation function params are always injected into inherent data; qed', /Users/right/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/05cc5f0/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:579:74
Jun 02 09:39:36 Parami-AWS-SFO-DANA-01 parami[490]: 2022-06-02 09:39:36 Proposing failed: ClientImport("Application(Application(Execution(Other(\"Wasm execution trapped: wasm trap: unreachable\\nwasm backtrace:\\n    0: 0x4610 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\\n    1: 0x28c2 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h8566c1c199f4b1e9\\n    2: 0x5550 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_display::h03e149d96a13e8f5\\n    3: 0x5508 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_str::h2aae451d464e75d2\\n    4: 0x54e2 - <unknown>!core::option::expect_failed::h6512e249c1770a7a\\n    5: 0x37716a - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_inherent_extrinsics\\n\"))))")
```

When go to the source code, we see the following code in parachain-system:

```
fn create_inherent(data: &InherentData) -> Option<Self::Call> {
        let data: ParachainInherentData =
            data.get_data(&Self::INHERENT_IDENTIFIER).ok().flatten().expect(
                "validation function params are always injected into inherent data; qed",
            );
 Some(Call::set_validation_data { data })
}
```

Our dependency of Substrate and Cumulus are as following:

```
sp-runtime = { git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate', branch = 'polkadot-v0.9.13', default-features = false }
 
cumulus-client-collator = { git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus', branch = 'polkadot-v0.9.13' }
```

And, our local rococo's version is also

```
0.9.13
```

We believe the most significant change in our upgrade is this one: https://github.com/parami-protocol/parami-blockchain/commit/41be91cfeb2aad91bed40bd4135af1a3809bda17

In our updated commits, there are no substrate or polkadot relative dependency upgrade. So we are lost in this problem. Any help or direction is preciated.

Comment: What environment are you in? Relay you are connecting to? Testing locally?

Comment: Why may I ask are you on such  outdated dependencies and what are you upgrading from yo 0.9.13?

Comment: @DanShields we are connect to local rococo which is used to act as the staging net before mainnet.

Comment: What version of rococo local? You cannot connect to mainnet at this old version

Comment: @DanShields We didn't upgrade any dependency of Substrate or Cumulus, this upgrade just carry our own pallet's modification. So I don't think the version is the really relative to this question(truly, it's too old).

Comment: rococo local's version is also 0.9.13.

Comment: Please update everything to the latest possible release (at this time that is 0.9.23)

Comment: what are you *starting* with and *going to* in this upgrade?

Comment: @DanShields In this upgrade, we just upgrade our self-define pallet.

Comment: Now, we begin to reproduce this scenario in our local dev machine, hope to reproduce it and get something close to the nature.

Comment: We have solved this problem, and I'll explain the whole thing later.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things to make sure:

- bump the [spec_version](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/upgrades/#runtime-versioning)
- use [`authorize_upgrade`](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/runtime-upgrades/#2-authorize---enact-an-upgrade-flow) and [`enact_authorized_upgrade`](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/runtime-upgrades/#2-authorize---enact-an-upgrade-flow)

Comment: 1. We have bump the spec version. 2. We use sudo.setCode to upgrade.

Comment: will sudo.setCode break this ?

Comment: You can use `setCode`- it does not break anything. It is fine to use. `authorize_upgrade` and then `enact_authorized_upgrade` is discrete where as `setCode` just bundles it all together.

Comment: Thank you, Bruno.